# Gluon Native/Mobile using java.awt.Toolkit

Tags: gluon-mobile, gluonfx, gluon-desktop

I have an app that uses java.awt.Toolkit in various places.

When I build it using Gluon (either native/mobile) and run it, I get the following error:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit at java.awt.Color.<clinit>(Color.java:277) at org.geotools.styling.FillImpl$1.<init>(FillImpl.java:43)`

Can I use AWT with Gluon (native or mobile)?

If so do I need to include something in my pom, gluon config, args, ..., to allow me to use AWT?

thx

I tried to use AWT and got a class not found error on java.awt.Toolkit. I had hoped it would work

Comment: I should have noted that I am not using AWT to draw to the screen, just to render an image into a buffer, which I then copy to a WriteableImage in JavaFX.

Comment: To follow up on my own question. AWT does not run via gluon mobile. JavaFX code worked perfectly however.